# Duplicate Dashboards should be avoided

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard page that displays several dashboards. I also have the liberty to choose which dashboards have to be displayed. But the problem is if I am choosing the same dashboard twice it is getting displayed. I want to put a restriction wherein if the dashboard is chosen twice only one should be displayed.[image]

The above image consists of two similar dashboards. I want only one among them to be displayed. How do I restrict this in JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: Before inserting dashboard check ids of dashboards that were already added and if it exists do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one line jQuery code if there is the same class for duplicate dashboards

```
$('.className').not(':last').remove();
```

It will just keep the last one and remove all others that are with the same class